# Custom validation rule checking existence with column name and filter

Tags: laravel, validation, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I want to validate that the user has selected a valid state value in an address form. For simplicity while developing, I'm not letting them pick the country yet.

The state information is in a table with the following fields:

```
id
country_id
abbreviation
name
```

The form uses a select element with name `address[state]` and sends the state ID as the selected value.

My first try at the validation rule was:

```
'address.state' => [
    'required',
    Rule::exists('shop_address_states')->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('country_id', 1);
    }),
],
```

But I get an `Unknown column 'address.state'` error.

When I try to get it to use the ID column instead:

```
'address.state' => [
    'required',
    Rule::exists('shop_address_states,id')->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('country_id', 1);
    }),
],
```

I get an `undefined offset: 1` error.

I guess I'm kind of mashing the rule `'state' => 'exists:states,abbreviation'` from https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-exists since I haven't been able to find an example elsewhere.

How do I get this rule to work?

Comment: I think Laravel is going to assume the column name from the data index. In this case, `address.state`. Have you tried explicitly passing the column name? `Rule::exists('shop_address_states', 'id')->where(...` notice the arguments are two separate strings.

Comment: @fubar ah - i think that might be where I've misstepped - I tried Rule::exists('shop_address_states,id') - make it an answer, and I'll give it a try when I can later today

Comment: hi there .. what is the value of `address.state` ? is it `id` or `abbreviation` ?

Comment: @Demonyowh `id`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel is going to assume the column name from the data index, if you don't explicitly state the column name. In this case, `address.state`.

When you have tried to add the column name, you're not passing it as a second argument in it's own right. Try the following instead:

```
Rule::exists('shop_address_states', 'id')->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('country_id', 1);
});
```

Comment: aha! found it in the API: https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Validation/Rule.html#method_exists